# Clerk is not protecting private routes in Next js

Tags: authentication, next.js, clerk

I'm using Clerk for authentication in my app. I've set protected routes using middleware like so:

```
import { authMiddleware } from "@clerk/nextjs";

export default authMiddleware({
  publicRoutes: ["/sign-in", "/sign-up"],
});

export const config = {
  matcher: ["/((?!.*\\..*|_next).*)", "/", "/(api|trpc)(.*)"],
};
```

The route `/` is not public without being signed in. Yet I can still navigate to it. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Whoops just acciedently put the ```middleware.ts``` file outside of my next app. All fixed now!

Comment: Additionally you probably dont need to have those routes in publicRoutes if you have them in your .env file

Answer (score 4):

I see that you figured it out, but for anyone else who has this issue, `middleware.ts` needs to be in the root of your project per the [docs](https://clerk.com/docs/quickstarts/nextjs#protect-your-application). In other words, if you're using the app directory, it would go in the same folder that contains the app directory (e.g., `C:\Users\[your name]\[your project]\middleware.ts`).